website font rendering automatically changes ś to ´s?
I've come across a bug (or an unwanted feature?), where the word "ryś" is rendered as "ry's". If ś is by itself, then it's rendered correctly.
The HTML markup:


* {
  font-family: "Patrick Hand", cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Patrick+Hand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h2>ryś ś</h2>



Rendering:

I'm not sure where or how to dig to figure out how to fix this, any ideas anyone?

The font is "Patrick Hand" (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Patrick+Hand?preview.text=ry%C5%9B)

Do you have any additional styles applied to that element, because I can not reproduce it.

Which browser are you using? I'm using firefox, I'll check Safari

I have edited your question with SO Snippet, please edit question with adding additional styles/surrounding elements until you can reproduce it here too.

@Justinas I tried removing all other styling, and it still renders wrong

Ah maybe something inherited, I'll try just creating a blank page with only that styling.

You're right! It works when I have an otherwise empty page, and this is the only styling applied to *. Thank you! I'll add stuff back, little by little to see what's causing this.

Now I'm unable to reproduce. Even if I checkout an earlier commit, it still renders correctly now. ^__^'

Most likely browser is rendering wrong temporary.
